# why a vector of cv::mat always return the first image?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I'm reading video frames from a webcam and storing them in a std::vector < cv::mat > variable.

Each time I want to calculate the frame difference between two consecutive frames, I use the following code but the result is always zero and I get a zero matrix !! I have two threads in my program, one for reading video frames and one for processing the video frames.
 whenever I'm going to write into the vector I use a mutex in order to prevent any further problems in pushing back or removing frames.

Here is my pseudo code :

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> IMAGE_VEC;
Qmutex IMAGE_VEC_MUTEX;
Main_Thread()
{

while(1)
{
 cv::Mat Frame,Reserved_Frame;
 Camera.read(Frame);
 Frame.copyTo(Reserved_Frame);
 QMutexLocker Locker(&IMAGE_VEC_MUTEX);
 IMAGE_VEC.pushback(Reserved_Frame);
 Locker.unlock();
 cv::imshow("Frame",Frame);
 cv::waitKey();
}
}
```

And My process Thread is:

```
Process_Thread()
{

  for (; IMAGE_VEC.size() > 1 ;)
{
      cv::Mat frame1;
      IMAGE_VEC[0].copyTo(frame1);
      cv::Mat frame2;
      IMAGE_VEC[1].copyTo(frame2);
      cv::subtract(frame1,frame2,result);
      QMutexLocker Locker(&IMAGE_VEC_MUTEX);
      IMAGE_VEC[0].release();
      //qDebug()<<"IMAGE_VEC Step2 size  is: "<<IMAGE_VEC.size()<<"\n";
      IMAGE_VEC.erase(IMAGE_VEC.begin());
      Locker.unlock();
}
}
```

I calculated the mean and standard deviation of each frame in Process thread and they were always the same ! I could solve this problem by changing the thread process code to this code

```
 Process_Thread()
{

  for (; IMAGE_VEC.size() > 1 ;)
{
      cv::Mat frame1;
      IMAGE_VEC[0].copyTo(frame1);
      QMutexLocker Locker(&IMAGE_VEC_MUTEX);
      IMAGE_VEC[0].release();
      //qDebug()<<"IMAGE_VEC Step2 size  is: "<<IMAGE_VEC.size()<<"\n";
      IMAGE_VEC.erase(IMAGE_VEC.begin());
      Locker.unlock();
      delay_ms(1000); // more than 1 second delay !!!
      cv::Mat frame2;
      IMAGE_VEC[0].copyTo(frame2);
      cv::subtract(frame1,frame2,result);

}
}
```

why this happens ? why a delay more than 1 second should be used to make this code work ? I tried it with a delay less than 1 second and the result were as previous step ...

I'd appreciate your comments on this.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to  copy or clone your frame to another Mat, then push to your vector, change your code like

```
 cv::Mat Frame;
 Camera.read(Frame);

 Mat tmp=Frame.clone(); //clone frame to new Mat
 IMAGE_VEC.pushback(tmp);
```

Otherwise you are passing same pointer on each pushback.

Comment: I forget to mention that I've done this too, but the result is still like the above code ... I've changed the code to your style to prevent any ambiguity

Comment: Also , Why in the second version by adding a delay the problem will be solved ? I don't want to use such a big delay in my code ....!

Comment: Make sure that you are not passing the same frame every time, you can test it by writing frame number on each frame after grab and check it from other thread.

Comment: what do you mean by adding frame number to each frame ? you mean I should add some numbers into the header ?

Comment: ooooooooops it's the same frame !!!! the only difference between my original code and the posted code is that Reserved_Frame is a global variable. is this the source of the problem if so, why a delay of more than 1 second will solve it ? my frame rate is 30 , so every 33 ms I have a new frame stored in the vector ....

Comment: The problem is not solved !!!! I solved the problem by adding a huge delay :((, I just tested your comments and realized they're the same frame, but I don't know why !!!!